# sum from a range of numbers in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

```js
function range(start, end) {
    var arr = [];
    for (var i = start; i < end + 1; i += 1)
        arr.push(i);
    return arr;
    function sum() {
        arr.reduce(function (a, b) {
            return a + b;
        }, 0);
    }
};
console.log(range(5, 15));
console.log(sum());
```

Can someone please tell me why am not getting the sum of **arr**.The sum keeps returning **0**

Comment: Your code as posted gives a runtime error. You should define `sum` outside of `range`

Answer (score 1):

You sum function should not be nested into the range function.
Your sum function should also take an array as parameter, here is the code updated:

```
function range(start, end) {
    var arr = [];
    for (var i = start; i < end + 1; i += 1)
        arr.push(i);
    return arr;
}
function sum(arr) {
   arr.reduce(function (a, b) {
     return a + b;
   }, 0);
}

var arr = range(5, 15);
console.log(arr);
console.log(sum(arr));
```

Answer (score 1):

The function `sum` is not defined in the right scope.

Try this :

```js
function range(start, end) {
        var arr = [];
        for (var i = start; i < end + 1; i += 1)
            arr.push(i);
        return arr;
    
    };
    
    function sum(arr) {
        return arr.reduce(function (a, b) {
            return a + b;
        }, 0);
    }
    console.log(range(5, 15));
    console.log(sum(range(5, 15)));
```

Comment: /home/marto/Desktop/func.js:246
    arr.reduce(function (a, b) {
        ^
TypeError: Object 2 has no method 'reduce'
    at sum (/home/marto/Desktop/func.js:246:9)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/marto/Desktop/func.js:48:13)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:935:3

Comment: what does this mean?  @zenoo

Comment: I forgot a `return` statement. it's fixed now.

Comment: still getting an error.How come your code is running?THIS ERROR 
     /home/marto/Desktop/func.js:246
         return arr.reduce(function (a, b) {
               ^
     TypeError: Cannot call method 'reduce' of undefined

Comment: I added a snippet in my answer, you can see everything works. From your error I would guess you didn't call the function `range` correctly, resulting on `arr` being something else than an array.

Answer (score 1):

you can try this:

```
function range(start, end) {
    var arr = [];
    for (var i = start; i < end + 1; i += 1)
        arr.push(i);
    return arr;
}

function sum(arr) {
       return arr.reduce(function (a, b) {
            return a + b;
        }, 0);
}
var tmp1 = range(5, 15);
console.log(tmp1);
console.log(sum(tmp1));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 var arr = [];
 function range(start, end) {

    for (var i = start; i < end + 1; i += 1)
        arr.push(i);
    return arr;

 }
 function sum() {
    return arr.reduce(function (a, b) {
            return a + b;
        }, 0);
     }
  console.log(range(5, 15));
  console.log(sum());
```

Comment: i still keep getting this error: /home/marto/Desktop/func.js:246
    return arr.reduce(function (a, b) {
               ^
TypeError: Cannot call method 'reduce' of undefined